# How can I synchronize two threads in Java by extending the Thread class?

Tags: java, synchronization

I am learning synchronization in Java and I cant find out why I cant get 24000 as a result for "c.count". When I run the code I get 23674, 23853, etc.
Do you have any idea why?

````
public class Counter {
    public int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        Counter c = new Counter();
        
        ThreadT t1 = new ThreadT(c);
        ThreadT t2 = new ThreadT(c);        
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(c.count);

    }
}

class ThreadT extends Thread {
    Counter c;

    ThreadT(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12000; i++) {
            add();
        }
    }

    synchronized void  add() {
    c.count++;
    }
}```
````

Comment: How is this different from the [same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66136163/642706) you asked yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `t1` calls `add` on the `t1` object while `t2` calls `add` on the `t2` object. While `add` is synchronized, `t1` and `t2` are two different objects, so the two threads are not synchronizing *with each other*.

Each thread calls a synchronized method on its own thread object, so it synchronizes only with itself. You need both threads to call synchronized methods on the same object.